# Ray & Physics.Raycast Constructor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I'm new to Unity .
**First question.** .
I got some sample code from internet, the third parameter uses `out hit` .
But the tip shows should be `distance`, and it actually worked. Why?
[image]

**Second question** . 
I can't new the `Ray Class` by origin and direction parameter .
My Unity Version 2017.4 .
[image]

Comment: First of all post code instead of pictures.

Comment: sorry I know that but I want to show the tip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The third parameter uses out hit . But the tip shows should be
>   distance, and it actually worked. Why?

**1**.The third parameter is not `out hit`. This depends on the method overload used.

The `Raycast` function has about **16** method overloads which means there are about 16 different ways to use it by providing different argument to them. You are new to Unity but this has more to do with C# programming language than Unity. If you don't know what method overloading is, read [this](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx) post.

With the example in your question, this is the overload you are using:

```
public static bool Raycast(Vector3 origin, Vector3 direction, out RaycastHit hitInfo, float maxDistance);
```

Notice that the last parameter is `maxDistance` not `layerMask`. to use the max distance and layer mask, use this, that should be `Physics.Raycast(transform.position, rayDirection, out hit, distance, layerMask)` and below is the overload for that:

```
public static bool Raycast(Vector3 origin, Vector3 direction, out RaycastHit hitInfo, float maxDistance, int layerMask);
```

These are other available overloads for the `Raycast` function:

```
public static bool Raycast(Ray ray);
public static bool Raycast(Vector3 origin, Vector3 direction);
public static bool Raycast(Ray ray, float maxDistance);
public static bool Raycast(Ray ray, out RaycastHit hitInfo);
public static bool Raycast(Ray ray, out RaycastHit hitInfo, float maxDistance);
public static bool Raycast(Vector3 origin, Vector3 direction, out RaycastHit hitInfo);
public static bool Raycast(Vector3 origin, Vector3 direction, float maxDistance);
public static bool Raycast(Ray ray, float maxDistance, int layerMask);
public static bool Raycast(Ray ray, out RaycastHit hitInfo, float maxDistance, int layerMask);
public static bool Raycast(Ray ray, [DefaultValue("Mathf.Infinity")] float maxDistance, [DefaultValue("DefaultRaycastLayers")] int layerMask, [DefaultValue("QueryTriggerInteraction.UseGlobal")] QueryTriggerInteraction queryTriggerInteraction);
public static bool Raycast(Vector3 origin, Vector3 direction, out RaycastHit hitInfo, float maxDistance);
public static bool Raycast(Vector3 origin, Vector3 direction, float maxDistance, int layerMask);
public static bool Raycast(Ray ray, out RaycastHit hitInfo, [DefaultValue("Mathf.Infinity")] float maxDistance, [DefaultValue("DefaultRaycastLayers")] int layerMask, [DefaultValue("QueryTriggerInteraction.UseGlobal")] QueryTriggerInteraction queryTriggerInteraction);
public static bool Raycast(Vector3 origin, Vector3 direction, out RaycastHit hitInfo, float maxDistance, int layerMask);
public static bool Raycast(Vector3 origin, Vector3 direction, [DefaultValue("Mathf.Infinity")] float maxDistance, [DefaultValue("DefaultRaycastLayers")] int layerMask, [DefaultValue("QueryTriggerInteraction.UseGlobal")] QueryTriggerInteraction queryTriggerInteraction);
public static bool Raycast(Vector3 origin, Vector3 direction, out RaycastHit hitInfo, [DefaultValue("Mathf.Infinity")] float maxDistance, [DefaultValue("DefaultRaycastLayers")] int layerMask, [DefaultValue("QueryTriggerInteraction.UseGlobal")] QueryTriggerInteraction queryTriggerInteraction);
```

---

> I can't new the `Ray` Class by origin and direction parameter.

**2**.You can't use the `Ray` class because you created a script named `Ray`. This `Ray` class doesn't have a constructor. Unity already has an API named [Ray](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Ray.html) and I am sure that's what you want to use. Do not name your script the-same name with any Unity API. If you do, it won't know which one to use (your Ray class or Unity's `Ray` class).

You have two options:

**A**.Rename your `Ray` class to something else

**B**.Let the compiler know that you want to use Unity's `Ray` class instead of your own by providing Unity's `Ray` class namespace which is the `UnityEngine`.

```
RaycastHit hit;
int layerMask = 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("LayerName"); ;
float distance = 100;

UnityEngine.Ray ray = new UnityEngine.Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, distance, layerMask))
{

}
```

Comment: Oh That's too foolish to create two identical name of class, so sorry
Yeah I know that's overloading, but where did you find these all method
I only got four methods in official documentation
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

Comment: Some functions are not listed on the doc. I use visual studio to find other function overloads. Right-click on the `Physics.Raycast` function then select "Go To Definition". You''ll see those lists

Answer (score 1):

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dhe1hce.aspx
2. Ray class is exist in Unity - just using the namespace or rename